# performance of int Array vs Integer Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance

Today when I submitted a solution to codeforces, I used int[] array and my submission got TLE(Time limit exceeded) & after changing it to Integer[] array surprisingly it got AC. I didn't get how the performance is improved.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    static class Task {
        public void solve(InputReader in, PrintWriter out) throws Exception {
            int n = in.nextInt();
            Integer[] a = new Integer[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = in.nextInt();
            Arrays.sort(a);
            long count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) count += Math.abs(i + 1 - a[i]);
            out.println(count);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        InputStream inputStream = System.in;
        OutputStream outputStream = System.out;
        InputReader in = new InputReader(inputStream);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
        Task task = new Task();
        task.solve(in, out);
        out.close();
    }


    static class InputReader {
        public BufferedReader reader;
        public StringTokenizer tokenizer;

        public InputReader(InputStream stream) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream), 32768);
            tokenizer = null;
        }

        public String next() {
            while (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try {
                    tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            return tokenizer.nextToken();
        }

        public int nextInt() {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @sotirios-delimanolis could you explain where the autoboxing happens? If the array is of type `int[]`, there should be no auto(un)boxing.

Comment: @NaveenKakani auto(un)boxing does not apply here, or at least not in a positive way. From what I see, auto(un)boxing should make your code slower, not fast. P.S.: [link to Oracle's tutorial on autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: @NaveenKakani the only thing you changed was the type of the array `a` in  `solve(...)` from `int[]` to `Integer[]` and your program got faster?

Comment: does it mean auto unboxing made code slower. Is that it?

Comment: @Turing85 Yes. you can look at my codeforces submissions http://codeforces.com/submissions/naveenkakani
problem 285C

Comment: @NaveenKakani yes, if Java auto(un)boxes variables, there is a runtime overhead.

Comment: Tnx @Touring85 got it. But, first i thought it as an IO problem lol :D now I'm very clear.

Comment: Did some testing with your code. The performance is not lost within `Arrays.sort(...)`, sorting an `int[]` this way is about 3x faster than sorting an `Integer[]`.

Comment: @naveen , I don't think your code performance has been improved due to auto-boxing  because when I execute my code , I got t1=0 and t2=0;

Comment: (Note that you don't even need to store inputs not exceeding one: just accumulate and count them.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason for it is quite simple: the time complexity of the solution with `Integer` is better.

Sounds strange, doesn't it?

`Arrays.sort` uses a dual pivot quick sort for primitives, which works in `O(N^2)` time in the worst case. The test case your solution fails is a specially constructed anti-quick sort test.

However, the version for objects uses merge sort, which runs in `O(N * log N)` time for any possible input.

Note that it's not a part of the Java language specification (it doesn't say how the `sort` method should be implemented), but it works like this in most of the real implementations (for example, it is the case for [openjdk-8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java))

P.S. Things like this happen more or less frequently in competitive programming, so I'll recommend to either sort arrays of objects or to use collections.